# apt update error on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, updates

I launched a container with ubuntu 22.04

```
docker run -it ubuntu:22.04
```

then got error with apt update

```
root@d089f7dbfc40:/# apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

the docker image info

```
"RepoTags": [
            "ubuntu:22.04"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "ubuntu@sha256:4b1d0c4a2d2aaf63b37111f34eb9fa89fa1bf53dd6e4ca954d47caebca4005c2"
        ],
```

I tried ubuntu:20.04, it works fine. And ubuntu:22.04 was working about two weeks ago.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution? I am also experiencing this. I've started a bounty on your question.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with the current Ubuntu 22.04 image, that should be filed as a bug report.

Comment: This does sound like a bug. Did you try running the rm -f command manually and with sudo privileges?

Comment: @ArturMeinild I found a solution involving updating Docker (see below). Do you still think this is worth filing as a bug report?

Comment: I think it was already reported and fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution! https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io/+bug/1998736

I was using Docker 20.10.9. After updating to 20.10.24 (latest available at this time), the problem vanished.